# Rails: Force user to create child object before saving parent

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms

I am a beginner at Ruby on Rails. Currently, I have the following problem: I have a class `Game` that has an array of pictures and sentences alternating. I want that a user who creates a new `Game` is required to give one starting picture OR sentence. If he doesn't do so I'd like to not save the newly created game to the data base.

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sentences
  has_many :paintings

  validates_inclusion_of :starts_with_sentence, :in => [true, false]

  [...]
end
```

My approach was that on /games/new, the user has to give either one painting or one sentence to begin with, but I am unsure how to enforce this, especially how to create and save a child object along with the parent object in one step.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So you've got two questions. The first (though second in your question) is "how to create and save a child object along with the parent object in one step." This is a common pattern and looks something like this:

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sentences
  has_many :paintings

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :sentences, :paintings # <-- the magic
end
```

Then in, say, `views/games/new.html.erb` you can have something like this:

```
<%= form_for :game do |f| %>
  <%= label :name, "Name your game!" %>
  <%= text_field :name %>

  <%= fields_for :sentence do |s| %>
    <%= label :text, "Write a sentence!" %>
    <%= text_field :text %>
  <% end %>

  <%= fields_for :painting do |s| %>
    <%= label :title, "Name a painting!" %>
    <%= text_field :title %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

When this form is submitted Rails will interpret the `POST` parameters and you'll end up with a `params` object that looks something like this:

```
# params ==
{ :game => {
    :name     => "Hollywood Squares",
    :sentence => {
      :text => "Buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo."
    },
    :painting => {
      :title => "Les Demoiselles d'Avignon"
    }
  }
}
```

And finally, in the controller that receives those `params`:

```
def create
  new_game = Game.create params[:game] # magic! the associated Sentence and/or
end                                    # Painting will be automatically created
```

That's a very very high-level peek at what you'll be doing. Nested attributes have their very own [section in the docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html).

Your other question is how to enforce this. To do that you'll need to write some custom validations. There's two ways to do this. The simplest way is with `validate`, e.g.:

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...

  validate :has_sentence_or_painting  # the name of a method we'll define below

  private # <-- not required, but conventional

  def has_sentence_or_painting
    unless self.sentences.exists? || self.paintings.exists?
      # since it's not an error on a single field we add an error to :base
      self.errors.add :base, "Must have a Sentence or Painting!"

      # (of course you could be much more specific in your handling)
    end
  end
end
```

The other method is creating a custom validator class which lives in another file. This is particularly useful if you need to do a lot of custom validations or if you want to use the same custom validations on several classes. This, along with the single method, er, method, are both covered in the [Validations Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html).

Hope that's helpful!

Comment: Hey Jordan, that was very great, thanks! I have one minor problem, if I implement it all like you mentioned, I get `Parameters: {"game"=>{"starts_with_sentence"=>"true"}, "commit"=>"Create Game", "painting"=>{"image"=>""}, "authenticity_token"=>"xxx", "utf8"=>"\342\234\223", "sentence"=>{"text"=>"This is a text"}}`, but Rails complains that `has_sentence_or_painting` fails. Any idea what could be the reason?

Comment: It might be I'm using `exists?` wrong in my code. Try e.g. `unless self.sentences.count > 0 ...` instead.

Comment: No, it seems like the sentence is not saved. The check is okay I think, if I disable it, the game is saved but without any sentences or paintings. It could very well be that something else in my code causes problems, since the Docs say that the Autosave function automatically saves childrne with parents. I have to do more debugging.

Comment: Okay, I got the mistake. Still don't know how to solve it, though. I have to write `f.fields_for`. Then however, rails complains that it doesn't know a field `sentence`, so I change it to `sentences`. But then, Rails doesn't create a form anymore, since there is no objects for `sentences`. If I write `@game.sentences.build` in `GameController.new`, then Rails creates a form but doesn't let it save me because it can't link the sentence to the game. I am a little bit lost. The same holds for `paintings`, and I am not able to let the user decide whether to create a `sentence` OR a `painting`.

Comment: Try `form_for @game` instead of `form_for :game` at the top.

Comment: I'm really good at getting things "essentially correct." ;) Thanks for the assist, @pduey.

Comment: Jordan's answer is essentially correct, and you nailed the issues that you have to 1. call "build" or "new" in the "new" and/or "edit" controller, 2. get the plurality correct in the form, and 3. call f.fields_for. Try adding game.sentences.new and game.paintings.new in the new/edit actions. Note, in the create/update actions, you should not need any code to persist the children, that's kind of the point - Rails will traverse the params hash/tree and persist each object, children first. Watch the debug logs and see what SQL is being executed (assuming SQL that is). Keep at it, it does work!

Comment: Got it working, thanks! The mistake was the `validates_presence_of :game_id` used in the model `Sentence`. I found out that I need to say `validates_presence_of :game` with `belongs_to :game, :inverse_of => :sentences`. I also solved the either-painting-or-sentence-problem by checking `@game.starts_with_sentence` and if so, setting `@game.paintings = []`. I have the feeling that it would be better style to solve this using `:reject_if`, but using `accepts[..] :paintings, :reject_if => proc { |s| starts_with_sentence }` seems not to work, he does not find the method `starts_with_sentence`.